# How can I combine these three blocks of code in jQuery and write them more elegantly/efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following three blocks of code and was wondering if I could somehow combine them so I don't have to keep writing the same code over and over again. Sorry if I'm explaining this funny. I just want to learn to write as elegantly/efficiently as I can.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="download-1">Tweet to Download</a></li>
<a href="#" class="download1">Download</a></li>

<a href="#" id="download-2">Tweet to Download</a></li>
<a href="#" class="download2">Download</a></li>

<a href="#" id="download-3">Tweet to Download</a></li>
<a href="#" class="download3">Download</a></li>
```

## 1

```
  // Download 1
  $('#download-1').tweetAction({
    url: 'download1',
    text: 'Download 1',
    via: 'twittersn'
  },function(){
    // When the user closes the pop-up window:

    $('a.download1')
      .addClass('active')
      .attr('href','download1.psd');
  });
```

## 2

```
  // Download 2
  $('#download2').tweetAction({
    url: 'download2',
    text: 'Download 2',
    via: 'twittersn'
  },function(){
    // When the user closes the pop-up window:

    $('a.download2')
      .addClass('active')
      .attr('href','download2.psd');
  });
```

## 3

```
  // Download 3
  $('#download3').tweetAction({
    url: 'download3',
    text: 'Download 3',
    via: 'twittersn'
  },function(){
    // When the user closes the pop-up window:

    $('a.download3')
      .addClass('active')
      .attr('href','download3.psd');
  });
```

Comment: Could you show your markup, please?

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You give them a common class instead of 3 different IDs, then just iterate with `.each` and use the `index` parameter `+ 1` where you need it.

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble I added the markup to the post.

Comment: @undefined: I don't think so, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap in in a function, thus:

```
function tweetFunc(id) {
    $('#download-' + id).tweetAction(
        {
            url: 'download' + id,
            text: 'Download ' + id,
            via: 'twittersn'
        },
        function() {
            // When the user closes the pop-up window:
            $('a.download' + id)
                .addClass('active')
                .attr('href','download' + id + '.psd')
            ;
        }
    );
}

for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    tweetFunc(i);
}
```

To get this to work, you'll need to sync the format of your download id attributes: is it `download-X` or `downloadX`?

Comment: but now you need `i <= 3` =P

Comment: Ha, the dangers of not testing! Thanks again @plalx. I think it means I need to have dinner `:)`

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. There will possibly be more downloads in the future so I can't set the number to three.

Comment: @Desi: so change `3` in the `for` loop to the number you end up using `:)`